# How to add logcat to ACRA

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat, acra

I'm trying to add my logs in ACRA.

I followed this [link](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#Adding_logcat,_eventlog_or_radiolog_extracts_to_reports) .

There they have stated

> adb logcat -t 200 -v time

This results to 200 lines of logcat with date, invocation time, priority/tag, and PID of the originating process.

But i donno where to add this in ACRA code such that this will update my Google Docs with this 200 lines of logcat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is to add the READ_LOGS permission to your manifest.

```
<manifest ...>
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

When you do this, ACRA will automatically add logcat information to your crash reports. The information that is added automatically is similar to the information you would get when you would execute `adb logcat -t 200 -v time` at the time of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you can receive reports and cannot obtain only one column choose this things:

- Check that you have requaried permission
  (`android.permission.READ_LOGS`) in your manifest file
- Check that if you use `customReportContent` attribute in your `@ReportCrashes`
  annotation you don't forgot to add `LOG_CAT` field
- Check that your google docs template has related column
- And this is impossible, but check that your logcat log is not empty:) write something in log before crash